# What happens to gold after the auction houses closure?

Tags: diablo-iii

I managed to save up $1 in the auction house.  Will I ever see the money again?

What happened to the money I earned from auctions now that auction house has closed?

Comment: Why was this closed?  This question is about neither unreleased nor illegal content - it appears to be perfectly on-topic.

Comment: Because apparently people don't agree with me that it's merely "too broad" and borderline "unclear".

Answer (score 5):

Your money isn't really gone but it also hasn't ever been in the auction house itself. All money you've earned with auctions is still in your Battle-Net account. You can think of it as a bank account provided by Blizzard. The money linked to your account can be used to buy Blizzard games, WoW playtime and in-game Items from the Blizzard store.

For in-game gold [battle.net](https://us.battle.net/support/en/article/diablo-iii-auction-house-removal) says:

> To claim items or gold from a completed or expired auction, visit the **Completed** tab in the auction house interface. You can claim completed auctions until Jun. 24, 2014—after that, the Auction House interface will no longer be available in-game. Any items or gold left unclaimed as of Jun. 24th will be permanently lost.

This is from the US battle.net page and since you wrote about dollars I assume you are asking about the american game servers.

For EU the same date counts. ([English](https://eu.battle.net/support/en/article/diablo-iii-auction-house-removal), [Deutsch](https://eu.battle.net/support/de/article/D3-Auktionshaus-entfernt), [Français](https://eu.battle.net/support/fr/article/fermeture-de-lhotel-des-ventes), [Italiano](https://eu.battle.net/support/it/article/la-rimozione-della-casa-daste-di-diablo-iii), [Español](https://eu.battle.net/support/es/article/retirada-de-la-casa-de-subastas-de-diablo-iii))